# 読みます or 読んで form to express habit

Tags: grammar, て-form

In my textbook it says you can use the 読みます form to talk about habitual actions, such as

私はよく本を読みます

But I read on the internet ([source](http://japanese.about.com/od/grammarlessons/a/031101c.htm)) that the correct form for this is 読んで and the sentence should be

私はよく本を読んで

Is my textbook wrong?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source of your internet information?

Comment: http://japanese.about.com/od/grammarlessons/a/031101c.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're just missing what the source is referring to.

The part where it says

> It is also used to describe a habitual action and a condition.

Is referring to this:

> (2) The present progressive: the ~ te form iru or imasu (formal)

So it's not referring to the て form but the ている/ています construction.

So for example, 私はひまなとき本を読んでいます。

Note also that this doesn't mean that ている is used *exclusively* to describe a habit. Just that it can be.